# How to load a UIImageView after loading the view controller

Tags: xcode, sqlite, uiimageview, blob, xcode4.3

I have a (probably) very slow and inefficient collage that I generate on a particular view controller. It takes forever to load, so I am looking for suggestions that would either speed up my SQLite query (it's searching BLOBs of saved images) or cause the SQL query method to be called **after** the viewcontroller loads, and then I'll put an activity indicator while it's loading.

Here are code snippets.

`viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //generate photo collage
    wineryName = theWineOfCurrentWinery.winery;
    [self obtainImagesForWines:wineryName];

    //lots of other stuff
}
```

`obtainImagesForWines` function. This is controlling the photos that show up in one of 16 UIImageViews, there is a 4x4 block of them:

```
- (void) obtainImagesForWines:(NSString *)theWineryName {

sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
sqlite3 *cruddb;

//sql command
const char *sql = "SELECT photo FROM wines WHERE winery=? AND photo NOT NULL ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 16";

//Open db
sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &cruddb);

int j=0;
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(cruddb, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { 
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [theWineryName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        UIImage *winePhoto;

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, 0) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, 0)];            

        if (data) {
            winePhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }

        switch (j) {
            case 0:
                image1.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 1:
                image2.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 2:
                image3.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 3:
                image4.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 4:
                image5.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 5:
                image6.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 6:
                image7.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 7:
                image8.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 8:
                image9.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 9:
                image10.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 10:
                image11.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 11:
                image12.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 12:
                image13.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 13:
                image14.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 14:
                image15.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            case 15:
                image16.image = winePhoto;
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"wtf?");
        }
        j++;
    }
}
else {
    printf("I can't get the wine photo by ID!!: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(cruddb));
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(cruddb);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run this method in the background (in other words "after view did load"), I used the following code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(obtainImagesForWines) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: Actually no, what this method does is, it starts loading the images in a background thread so that the main GUI doesnt get blocked. This is why it looks like its doing it after the viewDidLoad but in reality it is doing it along the viewDidLoad. Also i dont think having them as blobs is such a good idea since you cant take advantage of having them as assets like getting incredibly fast a thumbnail view to create your collages.

Comment: Do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: unless you store images in another way no, this will work for your case. because you also dont need that much control on how its executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try downsizing the image when you are displaying/storing them. I am not sure, but I think you are showing a pretty big image within your imageview. I believe you are trying to show a 16 image thumbnail. IF so, try compressing the image.

A possible better option, when you are storing the image, you could have the actual image stored along with the thumbnail version, so when you are showing smaller image, use the smaller one. and so on.

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,compressionRatio);
```

This should allow you to compress the image. OR if you want to resize them like this:

```
UIImage *yourImage = [UIImage imageWithData:yourdata];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:yourImage];
UIImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, yourImage.size.width / 2, yourImage.size.height / 2);
```

Hope this help!!

**UPDATED:**

There seem to be a lot of argument around stackoverflow on the use of sqlite BLOB to store image and there is a huge performance issue involved here. One such example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192945/to-reterive-blob-image-from-sqlite).

I had multiple scenario myself where I had to save images. What I did (all of my solution) was save the image to the document folder and then have core data (or sqlite if you prefer) store references to the image location and name. This way, the read time from the DB is lowered and time is also lowered.

I used the following function as a generic method to get the documents location:

```
- (NSString *)getFileLocation {
    // Get all available file system paths for the user
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    // Get the "Documents" directory path - it's the one and only on iPhone OS
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Specify the file name, appending it to documentsPath above
    NSString *savedFileName = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Location.plist"];

    // We're done
    return savedFileName;
}
```

The file location is then saved to the DB as string. I would recommend using the Core Data for better performance.

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily the size of the images that's a problem because I get a very long delay even on loading this view controller for the case when there are 0 photos saved where winery=?. It takes just as long to load when there are 0 pics as when there are 16. I'm sure that compressing pics is a good idea but if there are 1000s it doesn't matter if they are big or small to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the code which will take some time to another method like `ViewDidAppear`
or please run it in the background which will cause much more hassle when you try to udpate the UI from the background thread. so I will go for the first option and add the code into `ViewDidAppear` function instead.

If you want I can post code to run it in background but I will be misleading you as I will push you in a track that will force you to make more modifications for your code.